# Stop Autofac from filing IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, autofac, ienumerable

I'm looking for a way to stop Autofac from automatically filling an `IEnumerable<>` in my constructor.

For example, I have a class called School with the following constructors

```
public School(string name) {...}
public School(string name, IEnumerable<IStudent> students) {...}
```

You can use the first constructor to create the School object then use a AddStudent method to add the students to the school.

You can use the second constructor to create a School and pass in a collection of students to be added when the School object is constructed.

If I create `Func<string, ISchool> schoolFactory`, then call `schoolFactory.Invoke("Test")`, Autofac will use the second constructor and will automatically create a new Student object.

The IStudent interface and Student classes are registered with Autofac and the Student class has a default constructor. The default constructor is there because it's used in our UI when a user adds a new Student. The new Student is created with a blank name and the user can enter the name after the Student object has been created.

I tried the following ...

1. Remove the default constructor from Student. This works but it means I have to use a different constructor and pass in string.Empty for the student name. The main issue with this is that we have some other generic code for creating new objects that requires our classes to have default constructors. It's also not a solution for all of our classes.
2. Change `IEnumerable<IStudent>` to `List<IStudent>`. This works and it's what I started doing in our code, but it then forces the use of List<> instead of the generic `IEnumerable<>`. It's just less flexible.
3. Create `Func<string, IEnumerable<IStudent>, ISchool> schoolFactory` and use `schoolFactory.Invoke("Test", Enumerable.Empty<IStudent>)`. This also works. It's more code, but I guess it's more explicit.

Is there a generic way I can stop Autofac from automatically filling an IEnumerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. The short answer is: I think it's not possible. I'm not really a fan of saying no when it comes to software engineering, so here's a longer explanation:

What you see here is a so called "implicit relationship type" in Autofac. Specifically, [the one that supports resolving collections](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b). These are implemented in Autofac via [registration sources](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html). A registration source is a way to handle registrations dynamically based on given criteria (in this case, the collection aspect of the type). You can check these sources in your container in the `container.ComponentRegistry.Sources` property; the last one should be the one responsible for this. So in order to disable this functionality, you must be able to somehow remove this registration source from your container, but here's the catch: this property is of type `IEnumerable<IRegistrationSource>`, which means that it's readonly and is not meant to be meddled with (even though it's an array at runtime).

But if you are interested in other solutions to the problem, I can recommend different approaches:

1. You say you have a UI and the default `ctor` for `Student` is there so that the user interface can handle this type. Sounds like you are letting your user interface interfere with the design of your object model. I suggest you try implementing some architectural patterns designed to separate UI and BLL, like MVVM or MVC. In case of MVVM for example, you might have a `StudentViewModel` for the UI which can have a default `ctor`, and you can keep the Student clean with the parameterized `ctor` only.
2. In case this is not option (as you say it is not an option for all your classes), you can try to specify the constructor when you register your type ([see the docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#specifying-a-constructor)). In this case, you can manually register the non-collection constructor and Autofac uses that:

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<School>().UsingConstructor(typeof(string));
   ```

**EDIT**:

Or, if you are really keen on disabling the whole feature altogether, I guess you can go hardcore and open-source the s**t out of it :) Create your own fork, find the src/Autofac/ContainerBuilder.cs file and in the `void RegisterDefaultAdapters(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry)` method, you can see the default registration sources being added. Just delete the line that says `componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new CollectionRegistrationSource());` (line 247 on the develop branch in the file), then build your own and use that. Don't forget the modify the unit tests ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed replay. We are using MVVM. We created a generic `ViewModelBase<T>` that contains a `T Model` and `T EditMode`, When the view model is created, we pass in the object to be edited and we have a generic Copy method to copy Model to EditModel. We also have a generic AreValueEqual that we can use with Model and EditModel to see if the user change anything. The default ctor is used when the user creates a new item, unless there's reasonable defaults we can set. Just means we can use the business logic and validation of the model in the view model without duplicating it.

Comment: I'm going to look at the option of registering a specific constructor and compare that to being more explicit in our factories to specify the empty collection. I'll mark this as the accepted answer as it does provide some good options and detail. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm on a phone right now then on holiday... But if you pass ContainerBuildOptions.ExcludeDefaultModules to the ContainerBuilder.Build() call, it skips the implicit relationship modules. You can then manually register the ones you want. (Again, on phone, not coming back, can't verify this or give examples. Sorry.)

Comment: @TravisIllig I just checked and it works. This is a very useful piece of information that I did not know about (how did I not know about this??). The only problem with this solution is that after this, no source is registered - so how can you add back the needed registration sources, like the factory source? The class for that is internal in Autofac, so the only way that I can think about is creating a new container and copy the source from that, which feels hacky a bit...